# Pros and cons of multi-leader vs leaderless replication in databases?

Tags: replication, database-replication, distributed-system

What are all the pros and cons of multi-leader vs leaderless replication in databases?

Here are some I can think of:

- In multi-leader, client only writes to one leader so there may be lower latency
- In leaderless, you can generally tolerate a greater number of failures because as long as there are w nodes available for writes and r nodes for reads then the system can continue functioning

What are some of the other benefits / drawbacks of each approach?

Answer (score 0):

One non-trivial issue I see with leaderless databases is keeping the operations "in order".

If two clients issue a write request on the same key and each write is acknowledged by two different quorums of nodes, how do we decide which operation gets precedence?

The database would have to rely on a conflict resolution algorithm and/or logical time to determine the correct version.

Comment: This issue applies to multi-leader as well.